# How to solve the "'IndexOf'." error in PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, indexof

While running the below script I am getting an error:

> "Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject] doesn't contain a method named 'IndexOf'".

Please help me to find out a solution to avoid the above error while running the below script.

**Code:**

```
$serverlist_csv1 = Import-Csv -Path $file1
$serverlist_temp1 = $serverlist_csv1
$exclude_serverlist_csv = Import-Csv -Path $file2
foreach ($server in $exclude_serverlist_csv) {
    $servers1 = ($serverlist_csv1.'SourceHostName' | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty 'SourceHostName')

    if ($servers1 -contains $server.'Exclude Server') {
        $server_object1 = ($serverlist_csv1 | Where-Object {$_.SourceHostName -eq $server.'Exclude Server'})

        $serverindex1 = $serverlist_csv1.IndexOf($server_object1) 
        $dataResizable1 = {$serverlist_csv1}.Invoke()
        $dataResizable1.RemoveAt($serverindex1)
        $serverlist_csv1 = $dataResizable1
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `IndexOf()` in this context?

Comment: P.S. commenting your code is of huge benefit to all `;-)`

Comment: Your code looks needlessly convoluted. Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What are you trying to accomplish with your code?

Comment: I want to find out the index of an object in the list,once I identify the object ,I need to remove that object from another list.This will happen hen I do the comparison of two files.

Comment: The purpose of the code is to remove the list of servers in first file based on the second file details. The second file contains the list of the server details that needs to be removed in the first file.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because you used select-object on the pipeline invocation of $serverlist_csv1, which creates a layer over the object effectively creating a new object a pscustomobject and that makes it lose the indexOf() method.

if you avoid this step and instead try for instance to exclude that on the import of the csv or modify the member to nothing if that property isn't necessary to you. The point is like people before me said that does not seem like the better way to solve whatever problem this is.

Answer (score 0):

Build a list of the server names from the second file:

```
$exclude = Import-Csv $file2 | Select-Object -Expand 'Exclude Server'
```

Then filter the first file for rows whose `SourceHostName` column isn't one of those names and write the result back to a file:

```
Import-Csv $file1 | Where-Object {
    $exclude -notcontains $_.SourceHostName
} | Export-Csv 'C:\output.csv' -NoType
```